# Can't select objects with Select Circle

Tags: select

I can't select objects using the Select Circle by clicking on their mesh. It only works if I click on their axis. Select Box works normally: if I click a mesh, it selects that object. Is there an option I changed somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Can't say I've ever wanted to use Circle Select in Object mode but it seems to only select an object when you click on its origin in all my Blend files (including a new project) so I assume that's normal behaviour.

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you @JohnEason!

Comment: @JohnEason Strangely enough that in _Edit Mode_ all selection methods seem to work the same when selecting faces (in _Solid View_ you can select faces anywhere, in _Wireframe View_ only when selecting the center points), but in _Object Mode_ between _Select Box_ (selecting anywhere) and _Select Circle_ and _Select Lasso_ (selecting only on origins).

Comment: Yes. I know. Don't understand that, but I'm sure there's a good reason for it! :^)

Comment: Oh, that's the trick! Thanks a lot @JohnEason

Comment: Honestly, I would call this a bug not normal behavior. If you have several dozen strands of hair whose location is applied and whose origin is therefore at (0,0,0), then no one would think of selecting the objects at the world origin, especially when the mesh is at 1.8 m height. Hair strands are a mesh that has only edges. It's hard to click to select and you want to use *Lasso* or *Circle* select. But how can you select a single object if the origins are all at the same spot?

Comment: @Blunder It's a pretty long-standing one if it is a bug. I've just tried it in Blender 2.83 and it's the same in that! :^(

Comment: I've just had a look at the bug tracker. Indeed the behavior was already reported in 2014/Blender 2.79b: https://developer.blender.org/T39770 It was not fixed because "This is intentional behavior." -  But since 2018 there is hope and it's on the TODO list: https://developer.blender.org/T57209